# A dictionary within a class python

Tags: python

I have a code that creates a class (User) that contains two attributes called first_name, last_name, and several other attributes that are stored in a Dictionary (user_profile).

The problem is now that when I make an instance from the Class(user), the attributes that are stored in the Dictionary are not distributed correctly to the class variables . 
The code is below :

```
class User():
    """ summarize information about a user"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **user_profile):
        """initialize the user information like first, last names and others"""

        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

        # class attributes are stored in a dictionary

        for key, value in user_profile.items():
            self.user_inf = value

# make an instance          
user_prof = User('albert', 'einstein',location = 'princeton', field = 'physics')


print(user_prof.first_name.title() + " " + user_prof.last_name.title() + " " + "used to work in"+ 
   " " + user_prof.user_inf + " " + "at the" + " " + user_prof.user_inf + " " + "department")
```

Result:

Albert Einstein used to work in physics at the physics department

Expected Result:

Albert Einstein used to work in princeton at the physics department

How can I get the values of the dictionary in the right places in instances? Is there any way to index the values of a dictionary in the right order?

Comment: Please see [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help in diagnosis.  A couple of straightforward `print` statements in and near your `for` loop will show how your code *actually* works, allowing you to correct it.  Your posting shows that you know the basics -- you just need to look that one step of extra detail.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging whatsoever?

Comment: Thanks, I did debugging, the code works fine but output is not correct, I got the problem fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

the `for` loop from your class constructor it is overwriting to `self.user_inf` all the values from `user_profile` key arguments, as a result, the last value from  the key arguments  `user_profile` will be the value of `self.user_inf`,  to fix this you can use:

```
class User():
    """ summarize information about a user"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **user_profile):
        """initialize the user information like first, last names and others"""

        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

        # class attributes are stored in a dictionary

        self.user_inf = user_profile
user_prof = User('albert', 'einstein',location = 'princeton', field = 'physics')

print(user_prof.first_name.title() + " " + user_prof.last_name.title() + " " + "used to work in"+ 
   " " + user_prof.user_inf['location'] + " " + "at the" + " " + user_prof.user_inf['field'] + " " + "department")
```

output:

```
Albert Einstein used to work in princeton at the physics department
```